# Using JsonConverter to keep all datetime values formatted the same

Tags: datetime, json.net

I have a use case in which ALL date/time values must be saved in JSON documents using the following format:

```
yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff
```

In other words, all date/time values will be exactly 27 characters in length regardless of the date/time value, for example:

```
System.DateTime.MinValue = "0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000"
System.DateTime.MaxValue = "9999-12-31T23:59:59.9999999"
19-May-2018 10:35:12 am  = "2018-05-19T10:35:12.0000000"
```

Unfortunately, Json.Net decides to format date/times in various formats depending on the date/time value.  I have tried to use the JsonConverter attribute on date/time properties, ie:

```
[JsonConverter( typeof( datetime_iso8601_converter ) )]
public System.DateTime created_utc;
```

My converter class is as follows:

```
public class datetime_iso8601_converter : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.IsoDateTimeConverter
{

   public datetime_iso8601_converter()
   {

      // Set format that all DateTime values will use ...

      base.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff";

   }

}
```

If I run a test using the debugger, for example:

```
created_utc = System.DateTime.MinValue;
```

I can see the following line is executed:

```
base.DateTimeFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff";
```

However, the resulting JSON date/time value that gets written is:

```
"0001-01-01T00:00:00"
```

**SECOND ATTEMPT:**

I tried the following converter ...

```
public class datetime_iso8601_converter : Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.DateTimeConverterBase
{

   // The format that all datetime values will use ...

   private const String k_fmt_datetime_iso8601 = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffff";

   // Write the given datetime value using the format above ...

   public override void WriteJson( JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer )
   {

      if ( value is System.DateTime )
      {

         String dt_str;

         System.DateTime dt;

         dt = ( System.DateTime ) value;

         dt_str = dt.ToString( k_fmt_datetime_iso8601 );

         writer.WriteRawValue( dt_str );

      }
      else
      {

         throw new ArgumentException( "value is not System.DateTime" );

      }

   }

   // Return a datetime value ...

   public override object ReadJson( JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
   {

      if ( reader.TokenType != Newtonsoft.Json.JsonToken.Date )
      {

         throw new Exception( "Invalid token. Expected Date" );

      }

      return reader.Value;

   }

}
```

Again using the debugger I can see that **dt_str** is set to a value of:

```
"0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000"
```

but the value that actually gets written is:

```
"0001-01-01T00:00:00"
```

I do not understand why.

HOW can I get all date/time values saved in the format required?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?  [It works fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/p5sML8) when I try it.

Comment: Hi Brian - thanks for taking the time to check -- yes, I can get the above to work with a console application -- but the environment in which the above issue was failing was in Azure Functions -- which I should have mentioned in the original post - I apologize -- Microsoft has just confirmed that it is their library that is not currently supporting the binding redirects -- should be fixed in the next release of Azure Functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above issue was present in an environment that was using Azure Functions.  The current release of Azure functions 1.0.13 does not seem to support the binding redirects, i.e.:

```
[JsonConverter( typeof( datetime_iso8601_converter ) )]
```

However, [release 1.22.0 will support JsonSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sdk-dotnet#a-name12201220) and binding redirects (hopefully).

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same thing. The solution to is to override Newtonsoft's time format string and have it use `fffffff` instead of `FFFFFFF`

See https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2780#issuecomment-1363704872 for sample code and details.